# How to say if coffee is diluted and not strong?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

For instance, a cup of  cappuccino was made with too much water and because of it its taste was not that strong. What are correct words to say it? Dictionary returns many options, but which ones are the most appropriate for given context?

> Cappuccino is ***diluted | washy | watered | poor*** and ***weak | soft | mild***?

Comment: I'd use _weak_.

Comment: _Weak_ would be the word. @NVZ, even a _mild_ coffee can be brewed strongly.

Comment: @green [coffee.se] is worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

As a speaker of American English, I would use the word *weak* to refer to the kind of coffee you describe.

I might also call it *watery* or *watered-down*, but, while they mean the same thing, they're less common than *weak* in these circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

When I used to help out in an Italian family-run restaurant in London, the coffees ordered by American tourists were either called  *acqua sporca* ("dirty water") or *acqua nera* ("black water") by the waiters. Nowadays, long black coffees served  in Italian restaurants might be called *American coffee*, or a *long black*.

As for cappuccinos, if too much water (or milk) has been added, just say the beverage tastes more like ***weak*** white coffee than a proper Italian cappuccino.

Answer (score -1):

***Cappuccino is diluted.
Cappuccino is poor and weak.***

we can use both sentences.